# What is the android key-code for exclamation mark ? (!)

Tags: android, symbols

I was wondering if someone knows the key-code code for ! in android

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit obscure, but this [thread on Google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/y1Vu4y8ny2Y) provides the answer for a question mark:

> `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SLASH`, plus true for `isShiftPressed()`

I assume the same thing will work for an exclamation mark: `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1`, plus true for `isShiftPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Since ! and 1 are on the same key, you would want to check for the `KeyEvent`'s Unicode Character not its key-code. This probably is a better way to catch the exclamation mark, because some keyboard layouts may not have ! and 1 on the same key.

`keyevent.getUnicodeChar() == '!'`